# Upgrade to 19.10, LXD will no longer run

Tags: lxc, lxd, 19.10

I recently upgraded to 19.10.

LXD will no longer run, I get this error:

```
Error: Get http://unix.socket/1.0: dial unix /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket: connect: connection refused
```

I've checked and the lxd group is there, and my user is a member.

Comment: Have you tried updating lxd through snap or reinstall it?

Comment: Thanks. I got it working again by reinstalling, but I lost all of my existing containers in the process. Note to self-  make a proper backup of LXD containers before distribution upgrades.

Comment: :( excuse me for that, I didn't expect that behavior, thinking that it is standard to leave user config `~/` and `/etc`, `/var`,`/run` contents if not instructed by purge command.  Only if lxd make dist upgrade that is not compatible with previous one. It could be that images and settings are left in previous version folder without migrating them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalled snap package, lost data.